# ASP.NET application getting slower over time using Lucene.Net

Tags: asp.net, optimization, lucene.net

A website I have using Lucene.Net for search is progressively getting slower over time. I have set IIS to recycle the app pool at 1.5GBs.

After a recycle the app is fast again.

What are the best steps in diagnosing which parts of the search is causing the issue?

Its worth noting, it is definitely the search that's causing the issues as its only this part of the application which gets slow. A normal page loads fine regardless of time.

Comment: In the meantime you could recycle more often so your users don't notice.

Comment: Which version of Lucene are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you have analyzed your search code and it's too complex or not obvious what the slowdowns are, I would start with running performance monitors (perfmon.exe) and logging the results.   Look at change in CPU usage, memory, disk queuing, ASP.Net specific counters (requests queued, requests/sec) and CLR counters (pipeline instance count, exceptions thrown, context switches/sec, etc.).

Once you can zero in on some things that look out of the ordinary (growing unchecked over time by the sounds of it), you can start to narrow down any code problems.

Comment: can't spot anything in the search code, hence the head scratcher.

using perfmon, what exactly would I be looking for? I log all exceptions in my app, so I don't think there are bugs, just some unreleased objects or similar.

would using something like dot trace be a better tool?

Answer (score 0):

Do you optimize your index after big updates ? This can really improve performance.

Comment: I have found out what was causing it. It was when binding my filters / facets.

i diagnosed it by creating a script to request the page 100 times, then removed components one by one and watched the memory in IIS app pool. Once I removed the facets it was fine. Just need to do this a different way now and all will be good!